# Null Arraylist from Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-room

I'm doing weather app in Kotlin, and in Activity is method which firstly takes cache data from Room, and after one hour data is updated. But there is problem probably with saving of data in database. I checked API logs in Profiles and there is no null with Weather List, so API works fine.
I'm trying to save Weather list as an ArrayList, but the answer from logs is still null. I also tried Type Converter, but still nothing. Maybe someone will find the reason for my problem and the answer.

EDIT: I removed @Embedded(prefix = "weather_") above the ArrayList and it works.

CurrentWeather (stores Weather ArrayList):

```
@Entity(tableName = "current_weather")
data class CurrentWeather(
@Embedded(prefix = "weather_")
val weather: ArrayList<Weather>? = ArrayList(), //here is my problem
@SerializedName("base")
val base: String,
@Embedded(prefix = "clouds_")
val clouds: Clouds,
@SerializedName("cod")
val cod: Int,
@Embedded(prefix = "coord_")
val coord: Coord,
@SerializedName("dt")
val dt: Int,
@SerializedName("id")
val id: Int,
@Embedded(prefix = "main_")
val main: Main,
@SerializedName("name")
val name: String,
@Embedded(prefix = "sys_")
val sys: Sys,
@SerializedName("visibility")
val visibility: Int,
@Embedded(prefix = "wind_")
val wind: Wind

) {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
var idKey: Int = CURRENT_WEATHER_ID
}
```

Weather:

```
data class Weather(
@SerializedName("description")
val description: String,
@SerializedName("icon")
val icon: String,
@SerializedName("id")
val id: Int,
@SerializedName("main")
val main: String
)
```

Converter:

```
class Converters {

@TypeConverter
fun arrayListToJson(value: List<Weather>?): String {
    return  Gson().toJson(value)
}

@TypeConverter
fun jsonToArrayList(value: String): List<Weather> {
    val objects = Gson().fromJson(value, Array<Weather>::class.java) as   Array<Weather>
    val list = objects.toList()
    return list
}
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = [CurrentWeather::class, Location::class], version = 15, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class) //converter initialization
abstract class WeatherDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [Relation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation) instead?

Comment: No, but Relation works with List, not with ArrayList. If I set Weather as List, then I have problem with type :/

Comment: for what it's worth, you dont have to use `@SerializedName("")` for any variable which has the same name as the value from json

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thank you.

Comment: are you sure when you're saving it to the database it isn't null ?

Comment: I'm not sure now. In logs where I have cached data the Weather is always null, but when I tried to get data from Device File Explorer and read it in DB Browser files are empty. Strange...

Comment: I removed @Embedded(prefix = "weather_") above the ArrayList and it works. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the modified converter class. It might help you.

```
object class Converters {

    val gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun arrayListToJson(list: List<Weather>?): String? {
        return if(list == null) null else gson.toJson(list)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToArrayList(jsonData: String?): List<Weather>? {
        return if (jsonData == null) null else gson.fromJson(jsonData, object : TypeToken<List<Weather>?>() {}.type)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean value instead jsonData in jsonToArrayList?

Comment: @beginner992 yes, there were mistakes on variables. Now it is corrected. Take a look.

Comment: @beginner992 glad to know that.

Comment: @SagarChapagain I was writing the same logic for my TypeConverter as yours and it was not working and then now I tried copying your above code and now it's working like a charm  Anyways Thanks!

Comment: 3 hours to find this answer and solved a issue, yet another problem
TypeConverters() has private access in dao_impl,
Any Suggestions Please!